# Custom Token management in WCf

Tags: wcf, wcf-authentication

I have a webservice which passes raw messages using Message in WCF, I create the header 
MessageHeader.CreateHeader , now i want to implement a custom token management system  , so that i will pass the user name and password first time and then read the header in my service after authentication will provide a token to the user which will expire in some time, my webservice can have access by anonymous users and they have limited access .

I am using custom binding ...Any idea how to accomplish this or any sample...

Comment: You should accept some answers to your previous questions.

Comment: there should be an answer at least ,answers are  almost different, i was writing my requirement and people are asking y u need this

Answer (score 0):

Why not provide two endpoints for these two kinds of users?

And you can provide a custom AuthorizationManager to give them different authorization policy.

Comment: Thanks Jack, Actually i m new to WCF , i am providing a wsdl to the client as we are still not sure what the client will be flash , java etc etc , and in case i will use two endpoint i will have to wsdl url's